# Mediation analysis with between & within subjects?

Tags: mediation

I have a RCT data set as follows:

IV = Group (Intervention A, Intervention B, Control)

DV = Blood biomarker, Inhibitory control, working memory

I have two research aims.

1. Comparing the effect of interventions on DVs
2. Investigating the mediating effect of blood biomarker on inhibitory control and working memory

My results are as follows:

1. Interventions A and B decreased blood biomarker level.
2. Only Intervention A was effective on inhibitory control.
3. None of the interventions changed working memory.

In this case, I have three questions for mediation analysis.

1. Would performing mediation analysis only for inhibitory control make sense?
2. When analyzing mediation for inhibitory control, should I include only the intervention outcome that shows a significant effect (intervention A)?
3. Which method would be more advantageous for analysis (SPSS, AMOS, etc.)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should have a theoretical model already of what your IV, mediator and DV are. Here it seems, you are not sure what the mediator is or should be. As a reminder, the mediator is the mechanism through which the IV have an effect on the DV.

If inhibitory control is related to working memory, it would make sense to make it a mediator.

A likely model here is intervention -> blood biomarker -> inhibitory control. More information is needed to better grasp what you are trying to achieve.

AMOS should do the trick. In SPSS, you need a macro like PROCESS to carry mediation analysis. I would recommend R or Mplus or even any other software really.